# Componente vue no se muestra

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

tengo un problema he implementado el Scroll Infinito en laravel con vue tengo ese componente que me carga la información y otro componente que me muestra otro botón para que me abra un modal.

pero lo que pasa es que cuando cargo por primera vez la pagina a veces si me cargan los componentes. pero si le doy de nuevo actualizar . Ya no cargan, es muy random a veces cargan a veces no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

supuestamente quize separar en dos el archivo app.js e hice el selt.js porque estaba demasiado BIG! pero aún así sigue saliendo que cuando hago npm production salen muy grandes.

**en resumen
¿por que a veces no se muestran mis componentes hasta recargar varías veces la pagina? a veces a la primera aparecen.**

Comment: Pero adicional te sale algún error en la consola cuando no te aparecen? Sería bueno que pusieras el código tanto de los componentes que no se muestran, como del contenedor de este

Comment: No me muestra ningún error, como comente a veces cuando cargo recargo la pagina no sale nada y a veces si .